# Change Arduino Mega pin 2 and pin 3 PWM frequency

Tags: arduino, frequency, pwm

I am new to Arduino Mega. I am using it to build a switch mode regulator. I need to change Arduino Mega pin 2 and pin 3 PWM frequency to 10kHz or more than that. Appreciate if you can explain in simple way and provide example code at here, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the Timer/Counter Control Register.

This will give you an PWM frequency of about 62.7 kHz. The next possible smaller frequency would be 7.8 kHz. For this you would have to set bit `CS31` instead of `CS30`.

```
int pwmPin1 = 2;
int pwmPin2 = 3;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pwmPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pwmPin2, OUTPUT);

  //WGM30 = set Timer mode to PWM
  //COM3B/C1 = clear Output on compare match
  TCCR3A = (1<<WGM30)|(1<<COM3B1)|(1<<COM3C1);

  //CS30 = set prescaler to 1
  TCCR3B = (1<<CS30);  
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(pwmPin1, 127); //Change for your desired Duty-Cycle (from 0 to 255)
  analogWrite(pwmPin2, 63);
}
```